# Executing postgres script using jenkins

Tags: postgresql, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to execute postgres script using jenkis on remote server. Below are content of shell script. I am using publish over SSH plugin.

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql
```

```sql
CREATE USER sonar WITH PASSWORD 'sonar';
\du
CREATE DATABASE sonar WITH OWNER sonar encoding 'UTF8';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sonar TO sonar;
\l
\q
```

1) I can see contents are printed in terminal but not executed.

Solution I tried:

I created my scripts like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo -h myip -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"CREATE USER sonar WITH PASSWORD 'sonar';\""
sudo -h myip -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE sonar WITH 
OWNER sonar encoding 'UTF8';\""
sudo -h myip -u postgres bash -c "psql -c \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sonar TO sonar;\""
```

This script is working fine but I have to connect remote server multiple times. I want script to connect once and execute all psql queries.

2) I am also looking for dev and staging environment executed 1st and then production. Can we manage Plugin in this way?

Answer (score 1):

you can create file with all queries, lets say my_queries.sql and then run it like this:

`sudo -h myip -u postgres bash -f my_queries.sql`

my_queries.sql content:

```
CREATE USER sonar WITH PASSWORD 'sonar';
CREATE DATABASE sonar WITH OWNER sonar encoding 'UTF8';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sonar TO sonar;
```